# Jolt Transformation issue breaking apart records

Tags: json, apache-nifi, transformation, jolt

I'm trying to transform a record json into individual json records but have a hard time getting the values rather than the names. I expect the keys to change on occasion and there to be more than 4 records on occasion so I wanted it to be dynamic. It seems the current transform will only give me the keys and not the values broken out into there own records.

Input

```json
[
  {
    "Owner": {
      "0": "CIMections",
      "1": "CIMections",
      "2": "CIMections",
      "3": "CIMections"
    },
    "Name": {
      "0": "AFE 20NSF044",
      "1": "AFE 20NSF044",
      "2": "AFE 20NSF044",
      "3": "AFE 20NSF044"
    },
    "Producer": {
      "0": "Produtream",
      "1": "Produtream",
      "2": "Produtream",
      "3": "Produtream"
    },
    "Producers ID": {
      "0": "NTI XR 001-004",
      "1": "NTI XR 001-004",
      "2": "NTI XR 001-004",
      "3": "NTI XR 001-004"
    },
    "Weld - Real Time Count": {
      "0": "",
      "1": "",
      "2": "",
      "3": ""
    },
    "Character Set": {
      "0": "ISO_IR 192",
      "1": "ISO_IR 192",
      "2": "ISO_IR 192",
      "3": "ISO_IR 192"
    },
    "inv# Welds": {
      "0": "Accepted 001",
      "1": "Accepted 002",
      "2": "Accepted 003",
      "3": "Accepted 004"
    },
    "invoice": {
      "0": 893300361,
      "1": 411904740,
      "2": 673190473,
      "3": 1426231494
    },
    "status": {
      "0": "Done",
      "1": "Done",
      "2": "Done",
      "3": "Done"
    },
    "Date Completed": {
      "0": "20210301 163500.000000",
      "1": "20210301 163500.000000",
      "2": "20210301 163500.000000",
      "3": "20210301 163500.000000"
    },
    "Institution Name": {
      "0": "NXXT Digital",
      "1": "NXXT Digital",
      "2": "NXXT Digital",
      "3": "NXXT Digital"
    },
    "file_id": {
      "0": "00001",
      "1": "00002",
      "2": "00003",
      "3": "00004"
    }
  }
]
```

Current Transformation

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "Owner": "Owner.[].@(1,0)",
          "$": "&",
          "@": "@clientId"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Im Getting

```json
{
  "Owner" : "Owner",
  "Name" : "Name",
  "Producer" : "Producer",
  "Producers ID" : "Producers ID",
  "Weld - Real Time Count" : "Weld - Real Time Count",
  "Character Set" : "Character Set",
  "inv# Welds" : "inv# Welds",
  "invoice" : "invoice",
  "status" : "status",
  "Date Completed" : "Date Completed",
  "Institution Name" : "Institution Name",
  "file_id" : "file_id"
}
```

But wanting

```json
{
  "Owner" : "CIMections",
  "Name" : "AFE 20NSF044",
  "Producer" : "Produtream",
  "Producers ID" : "NTI XR 001-004",
  "Weld - Real Time Count" : "",
  "Character Set" : "ISO_IR 192",
  "inv# Welds" : "Accepted 001",
  "invoice" : "893300361",
  "status" : "Done",
  "Date Completed" : "20210301 163500.000000",
  "Institution Name" : "NXXT Digital",
  "file_id" : "00001"
},
{
  "Owner" : "CIMections",
  "Name" : "AFE 20NSF044",
  "Producer" : "Produtream",
  "Producers ID" : "NTI XR 001-004",
  "Weld - Real Time Count" : "",
  "Character Set" : "ISO_I 192",
  "inv# Welds" : "Accepted 002",
  "invoice" : "411904740",
  "status" : "Done",
  "Date Completed" : "20210301 163500.000000",
  "Institution Name" : "NXXT Digital",
  "file_id" : "00002"
}...
```

Comment: Oh i edited the values a little bit. Let me correct this information. Thanks for spotting it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$` wildcard is not needed, but only using `@` wildcard is enough, along with filtering by indices with **`0`** and **`1`** (**`0|1`**) such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "0|1": {
            "@": "[&].&2"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where prepending the value with **`[&].`** converts each individual array to seperate objects within a single array.

If you need to get all the objects within the array, then replace **`"0|1"`** with **`"*"`** wildcard.

Comment: Oh thanks so Much! But what if I want all the records to be listed? Not just the first two. Also you're always helping me on these questions! thank you so much!

Comment: Oh Ive got it. replaced 0|1 with "*"